# How prove $g(x)$ is odd function :$g(x)=-g(-x)$

Tags: real-analysis

**QUestion:**

> let $f(x),g(x)$ is continuous on $R$,and such
>   $$f(x-y)=f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y)$$
>   and $f(0)=1$
>
> show that: for any $x\in R$, have $g(x)=-g(-x)$

my try: let $x=y=0$,then
$$f(0)-[f(0)]^2=g(0)g(0)\Longrightarrow g(0)=0$$

and let $x=0$, note $f(0)=1,g(0)=0$,so
$$f(-y)=f(y)$$
since
$$g(x)g(y)=f(x)f(y)-f(x-y)$$
so
$$g(-x)g(y)=f(-x)f(y)-f(-x-y)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)$$
since
$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(-y)-g(x)g(-y)\Longrightarrow g(x)g(-y)=f(x)f(y)-f(x+y)$$
so
$$g(-x)g(y)=g(x)g(-y)$$

But I can't have $g(x)=-g(-x)$

Comment: Well you can already set $y:=-x$ to get that their squares are equal. And then, I suppose the continuity hypothesis must be used to prove they have same sign.

Answer (score 2):

*Since the proof comes directly from Kelenner's comment, I post this answer in community wiki, so as to not earn undeserved points.*

We assume $f(0)=1$ and

$$\forall x,y \in \Bbb R, f(x-y)=f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y)$$

*Notice that we use nowhere the assumption that $f$ or $g$ is continuous.*

Then, for all $x\in\Bbb R$,

$$1=f(0)=f(x-x)=f(x)^2-g(x)^2$$

And

$$f(2x)=f(x)f(-x)-g(x)g(-x)$$

Also, $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R$,

$$f(y-x)=f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y)=f(x-y)$$

Hence $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, $f(x)=f(-x)$, that is, $f$ is even.

Therefore, $f(-x-y)=f(x+y)$, or, $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R$,

$$f(-x)f(y)-g(-x)g(y)=f(x)f(-y)-g(x)g(-y)$$

Hence, $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R$, $g(-x)g(y)=g(x)g(-y)$.

Now, let's suppose $g(y_0)\neq0$ for some $y_0 \in \Bbb R$.

We have then, $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, such that $g(x)\neq0$,
$$\frac{g(-x)}{g(x)}=\frac{g(-y_0)}{g(y_0)}=a$$

Where $a$ is a constant real number.

And if $g(x)=0$, then from $g(-x)g(y_0)=g(x)g(-y_0)=0$ and $g(y_0)\neq0$, we have that $g(-x)=0$ too.

That is, $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, $g(-x)=ag(x)$.

But then $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, $g(x)=ag(-x)=a^2g(x)$, and since $g(y_0)\neq0$, we can simplify and $a^2=1$, or $a=\pm1$. Thus the function $g$ is either even or odd.

If $g$ is even, then $\forall x\in\Bbb R$,

$$f(2x)=f(x)^2-g(x)^2=1$$

So $f$ is constant ($=1$).

But then $\forall x\in\Bbb R$, $g(x)^2=f(x)^2-f(2x)=0$.

Hence, if $g$ is even, it's the null function.

But that means $g$ is always odd, since either it is odd, either it is null (thus also odd).

Answer (score 0):

Hint (using that $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $g(x)g(-y)=g(-x)g(y)$ the results form the question above).

$x$ should be arbitrary in the whole calculation.

With $\forall x,y\in R$ $$g(x)g(-y)=g(-x)g(y)\tag{i}$$
set $y\to -x$ then $$g(x)^2=g(-x)^2\tag{ii}$$

Because of $g$ is real $$g(-x)=\pm g(x)\tag{iii}$$
If there is any $x_+$ so that $g(-x_+)=g(x_+)$, then with (i) $\qquad\forall y\in R: g(-y)=g(y)$.

Or there is a $x_-$ with $g(x_-)=-g(x_-)$, then with (i) $\qquad\forall y\in R:g(-y)=-g(y)$

Thus the sign in $(iii)$ must be the same for all values of $x$.

Now starting with
$$f(x-y)=f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(y) \tag{1}$$
Set $y\to x$
$$1=f(0)=f(x)^2-g(x)^2\tag{2}$$

Now look at
$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)-g(x)g(-y)\tag{3}$$
Assume that $\forall x_+\in R:g(-x_+)=+g(x_+)$

Then set $y\to x_+$
$$f(2x_+)=f(x_+)^2-g(x_+)^2\tag{4}$$
Comparing $(2)$ and $(4)$ you see then $\forall x_+\in R:f(2x_+)=1$.

With $\forall x_+\in R:f(x_+)=1$ and $(2)$ you get $\forall x_+\in R$ $$g(-x_+)=g(x_+)=0=-g(x_+) \tag{5}$$ or the assumption was wrong.

In summary you get $$\forall x\in R:g(-x)=-g(x) \tag{6}$$
Did I make any bad mistakes or is something missing?

Comment: I see one problem: you assume that either $g(x)=g(-x)$ for all $x$, either $g(x)=-g(-x)$ for all $x$. But it could also "change sign".

Comment: I assumed this and lead this to a contradiction, if $g(x)$ is not null everywhere. Thus $g(-x)=-g(x)$. Or what do you mean?

Comment: But there are functions that are neither odd or even, you can't simply assume it's not possible.

Comment: I agree with Jean-Claude Arbaut. To resolve the problem, you can suppose that $g$ is not the zero function; then there exists $y_0$ such that $g(y_0)\not=0$. You get $g(-x)=ag(x)$ for all $x$, $a=g(-y_0)/g(y_0) $; replace $x$ by $-x$ and simplify.

Comment: You also can use $g(-x)g(y)=g(x)g(-y)
$ and set $x=-y$ as xaviermo2 said. Then you have $g(x)^2=g^2(-x)$ I used that implicit, if g is real, what I assumed by the tag of real-Analysis.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, and that does not tell you that $g$ must be even or odd.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: We have $1=f(x)^2-g(x)^2$ for all $x$ ($x=y$ in the functional equation)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut But compare the second and the 4th equation.

Comment: @Kelenner Ah, ok for this point. But the other remains ;-)

Comment: @Matthias: The problem is that in general $u(x)v(x)=0$ does not imply $u=0$ or $v=0$. (you try to use $(g(x)-g(-x))(g(x)+g(-x))=0$)

Comment: Actually, it implies that, for all $x$, either $u(x)=0$ or $v(x)=0$, not that $u(x)=0, \forall x$ of $v(x)=0,\forall x$. Problem with ordering of quantifier. It works with polynomials though (using an argument on roots)

Comment: Sorry I am to stupid to see where I used $u(x)v(x)=0$ implies $v=0$ or $u=0$. Tell where

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: Using $g(x)=ag(-x)$ as in my previous comment gives $a^2=1$, hence $g(-x)=g(x)$ or $g(-x)=-g(x)$.

Comment: @Kelenner Maybe I'm a bit slow today, but I don't see why the same $a$ is guaranteed to work for all $x$ ;-)

Comment: You get $f(2x) = 1$ only for the $x$ that satisfied $g(x) = g(-x)$.

Comment: @Matthias The problem is you write "Assume that $g(−x)=+g(x)$", does it mean "for all $x$"? If yes, how can you infer that, if it is wrong, then "$g(−x)=−g(x)$ for all $x$"? There is a problem with quantifiers. That something is true for one $x$ does not imply it's true for all.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: I have fixed a $y_0$ such that $g(y_0)\not =0$. As for all $x,y$ we have $g(x)g(-y)=g(y)g(-x)$, we get $g(-x)=ag(x)$ for all $x$ with $a=g(-y_0)/g(y_0)$.

Comment: @Kelenner Oh, yes!!! Very nice! With this it's ok then. (but only with this ;-))

Comment: $x$ can be arbitrary at every equation I wrote.

Comment: @Matthias No, it can't. Write quantifiers explicitly, and you will see what you write is wrong: as J.J. explains, that $g(x)^2=g(-x)^2$ does *not* imply that $g$ is either even or odd. The problem is you don't write quantifiers, so what works for a priori only one $x$, you assume is works for all $x$. What do you *exactly* mean by "Assume that $g(−x)=+g(x)$"? Then only thing you can infer from $g(x)^2=g(-x)^2$ is that, for all $x$, either $g(x)=-g(-x)$ of $g(x)=g(-x)$. But for only this $x$.

Comment: Try this with $g(x)=|\sin(x)|$ for $x<0$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$ for $x\geq0$. You have then certainly that $g(x)^2=g(-x)^2$ for all $x$. So what?

Comment: How do you conclude that $g(x_+)=0$? And then how do you conclude that $\forall x\neq x_+$, $g(-x)=-g(x)$? Where did you get that $f(x_+)^2=1$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Maybe with the use of contintuity and that $f(0)=1>0$ you can show that $\forall x: g(-x)=-g(x)$ or $\forall x: g(-x)=g(x)$ with the first $\forall x:g(x)=0=-g(-x)$ this is still odd

Comment: Kelenner gave a nice solution above, to overcome these problems.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut should I add this part of proof in the answer?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut is the whole proof now ok?

Comment: I have given the answer Kelenner probably had in mind, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I like these problems, so let me give it a try and write it down neatly.

Since the right hand side is invariant under the swapping $x$ and $y$ we have $f(-t)=f(t)$. Applying the identity with $-x$ and $-y$, using that $f$ is even, gives that $g(-x)g(-y) = g(x)g(y)$, for all $x$ and $y$. (1) Setting $x=y$ implies that  $g(-x)\in \{ g(x), -g(x)\}$ for all x.

If $g\not\equiv 0$, then take any $y$ such that $g(y)\neq 0$. Then either $g(y)=g(-y)$ or $g(y)=-g(-y)$, and substituting and dividing by $g(y)$ in equation (1) shows that $g$ is either even or odd. (Or identically zero but that's ok because both even and odd.)

If $g$ is even then applying the first identity with $x$ and $-y$, using that $f$ and $g$ are both even, results in $f(x-y)=f(x+y)$, thus  $f$ would be a constant namely $f\equiv 1$. Contradiction because then $g(x) g(y) = 0$ for all $x$ and $y$ , thus $g\equiv 0$ but we already dismissed that case.

Comment: Hmm did I use continuity? Let me know if you spot a mistake :-)

Answer (score -1):

First note that by using $f(x)=f(-x)$
$$
f(0) = f(x-x) = f(x)^2- g(x)^2  \\
f(0) = f(-x-(-x))=f(x)^2-g(-x)^2 \\
g(x)^2 = g(-x)^2 
$$
Thus let one define into two sets (note an element may be in both)
$$
\Gamma^+=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : g(x) = g(-x) \} \\
\Gamma^-=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : g(x) = -g(-x) \} \\
$$
Clearly $\mathbb{R}=\Gamma^+ \cup \Gamma^-$, such that $g$ is even for $x\in\Gamma^+$, and odd for $x\in\Gamma^-$.

Consider $x\in\Gamma^+$, one has
$$
f(x-y)=f(x)f(-y)-g(x)g(-y) \\
\therefore f(x-y)=f(x+y)\Rightarrow f(x-x)=f(x+x) \Rightarrow f(x)=1 \:\forall x\textrm{ as }f(0)=1 \\
\Rightarrow g(x)=0 \:\forall x \in\Gamma^+
$$
Thus $x\in\Gamma^+\Rightarrow g(x)=0 \Rightarrow g(x)=-g(-x)\Rightarrow x\in\Gamma^-$. Thus $\mathbb{R}=\Gamma^-$.

Comment: You have the same problem as Matthias. From $g(x)^2 = g(-x)^2$ it does not follow that $g$ is odd or even.

Comment: Why not, I don't understand?

Comment: Same comment as above. Try this with $g(x)=|\sin(x)|$ for $x<0$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$ for $x\geq0$. You have then certainly that $g(x)^2=g(-x)^2$ for all $x$. So what?

Comment: Take $u(x)=1$ for all $x$, $v(x)=1$ for $x$ rational and $v(x)=-1$ for $x$ not rational. You have $u(x)^2=v(x)^2$ for all $x$, but $u\not =v$ and $u\not =-v$.

Comment: @Kelenner Bad example. Not continuous ;-)

Comment: Because it implies just $g(x) = \sigma_x g(-x)$, where $\sigma_x = \pm 1$ is chosen separately for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: OK, Ok... your example is better.

Comment: @Kelenner It's just because it's in the problem statement. One could argue that the example does not work because it's not continuous, even though it's not the real problem here.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: Yes, it was only a remark that your example is more adapted with the hypothesis. Well I leave this discussion...Salut.

Comment: @Kelenner Bye !

Comment: @destroyer From $f(x-x)=f(x+x)$, you get $f(x)=1$? That you have $f(2x)=1$, yes, but $f(x)=1$, how?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut your right now I've changed so that $g$ isn't odd or even it no longer makes sense